# Generate additional artifact while creating reports or in another phase?

Tags: maven, report, artifact, doclet

I understand that you can create only one artifact from one pom in maven.

I wrote a javadoc doclet that creates an html report of my artifact (my-rest-api). This doclet can also create stub requests and models for writing integration tests. My problem is now, that I have to manually copy the generated classes into a third maven project (my-test-models) in order to create an artifact from it. Is there any other way? The generated classes are created from source so I cannot just depend on the my-rest-api artifact. I could hard-code paths between both project but I don't like that neither. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you can `install/deploy` the **source** of `my-rest-api` artifact and in your `my-test-models`, specify this as a `dependency`.

You can use [maven source plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) to do this.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>attach-sources</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: the request model sources are generated in the "report" phase. Isn't that after the 'jar' goal?

Comment: another issue that I cannot depend on that "source" artifact (i guess) without getting all dependencies of the binary artifact (which would be the whole server)